# Plotting curves containing constants using ezplot

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot a function using ezplot, different values of two constants.
like

```
ezplot('a*x^2+b*y^2=1')
```

How can I plot it for different values of a and b?
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is:

first define your function with a handler, something like this:

```
a = 1;
b = 3;
fh = @(x,y) (a*x.^2 + b*y.^2 - 1);
```

Then easily use ezplot with the function:

```
ezplot(fh)
axis equal
```

If you have different values of a, and b, you can use them in a loop (or using vectorized calculation), and feed them to your function, then plot the function, and after a plot use 'hold on' command to keep the previous plot something like this:

```
for i=1:n
    fh = @(x,y) (a(i)*x.^2 + b(i)*y.^2 - 1);
    ezplot(fh);
    hold on
end
```

That's it.

Comment: I think that the OP means more for variable `a` and `b`, not just for one value of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to use multiple values for `a` and `b`: define your function separately and use function handles and anonymous function to change `a` and `b`. You can define your implicit function as two separate functions:

```
function y = someFun(x,a,b)

y = sqrt((1-a.*x.^2)./b);

function y = someFun2(x,a,b)

y = - sqrt((1-a.*x.^2)./b);
```

Then call `ezplot` on an anonymous function using `a` and `b`.

```
clear all
close all
figure
hold on
for a = 1:5
    for b = 1:5
        ezplot(@(x)someFun2(x,a,b));
        ezplot(@(x)someFun(x,a,b));
    end
end

axis([-1,1,-1,1])
```

ezplot will reset the axis so you'll need to set those your self after it's called.